# How do I read environment variables in my Appwrite functions?

Tags: function, appwrite

In the Appwrite console, I'm adding a test environment variable to pass into function...

[image]

In my function code (NodeJs) index.js, I'm logging out the value of above variable...

[image]

I save the code and use the Appwrite CLI (createTag) to push/publish the code.

Then in Appwrite console, I activate the new function then I execute it and I see this in log...

[image]

Clearly I'm missing something but I'm searching the Appwrite docs and I don't see it.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you for helping :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like as of this post, this is a **bug** in the Appwrite web UI code. You can do this 2 ways right now. You can set the environment vars in code or you can use the Appwrite CLI. I ended up putting the CLI commend in my NodeJs package.json scripts for quick easy access.

Here are both ways that worked for me...

```
appwrite functions create --functionId=regions_get_all --name=regions_get_all --execute=[] --runtime=node-16.0 --vars={ 'LT_API_ENDPOINT': 'https://appwrite.league-tracker.com/v1', 'LT_PROJECT_ID': '61eb...7e4ff', 'LT_FUNCTIONS_SECRET': '3b4b478e5a5576c1...ef84ba44e5fc2261cb8a8b3bfee' }
```

```js
const sdk = require('node-appwrite');

const endpoint = 'https://appwrite.league-tracker.com/v1';
const projectId = '61eb3...7e4ff';
const funcionsSecret = '3b4b478e5a557ab8a...c121ff21977a';

const functionId = process.argv[2];
const name = process.argv[2];
const execute = [];
const runtime = 'node-16.0';
const env_vars = {
    "LT_API_ENDPOINT": endpoint,
    "LT_PROJECT_ID": projectId,
    "LT_FUNCTIONS_SECRET": funcionsSecret
};

// Init SDK
const client = new sdk.Client();
const functions = new sdk.Functions(client);
client
    .setEndpoint(endpoint) // Your API Endpoint
    .setProject(projectId) // Your project ID
    .setKey('33facd6c0d792e...359362efbc35d06bfaa'); // Your secret API key

functions.get(functionId)
    .then(
        func => {
            // Does this function already exist?
            if ((typeof (func) == 'object' && func['$id'] == functionId)) {
                throw `Function '${functionId}' already exists. Cannot 'create'.\n\n`;
            }
            // Create the function
            functions.create(functionId, name, execute, runtime, env_vars)
                .then(
                    response => console.log(response),
                    error => console.error(`>>> ERROR! ${error}`)
                );
        }).catch(
            error => console.error(`>>> ERROR! ${error}`)
        );
```

Comment: Make sure you setup your API keys with proper functions.read and functions.write permissions or the code will error.

Comment: Once you run one of above you will have access to the environment variables in your function code like... `process.env.LT_API_ENDPOINT`

Answer (score 0):

As of Appwrite 0.13.0, an Appwrite Function must expose a function that accepts a `request` and `response`. To return data, you would use the `response` object and either call `response.json()` or `response.send()`. The `request` object has an `env` object with all function variables. Here is an example NodeJS Function:

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const payload =
    req.payload ||
    'No payload provided. Add custom data when executing function.';

  const secretKey =
    req.env.SECRET_KEY ||
    'SECRET_KEY environment variable not found. You can set it in Function settings.';

  const randomNumber = Math.random();

  const trigger = req.env.APPWRITE_FUNCTION_TRIGGER;

  res.json({
    message: 'Hello from Appwrite!',
    payload,
    secretKey,
    randomNumber,
    trigger,
  });
};
```

In the example above, you can see `req.env.SECRET_KEY` being referenced. For more information, refer to the [Appwrite Functions docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/functions).